# Foreach for family members

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to program a php script for family tree but I have a question about something was hard to do for me.

Now I have a table at database called people which consists of

```
- id
- name
- parent
- is_first
```

I want to use foreach to show up the people which have 1 at is_first
then foreach the people who has parent = id for the greatest parents , then loop the last foreach to get the parents children using parent column.

Any help, please :")

That is my test

```
    $data['test'] = $this->Tree->getForloop($id,"people ORDER BY id","");

    foreach($data['test']->result() as $row){
        $data['test'.$row->id] = $this->Tree->getForloop($row->id,"people","parent"); // parent = $row->id at people
    }
```

but works for just 2 steps

Comment: You need to make function which will be called recursively for each member/record.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)